# Built an array with jquery events. How to trigger them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am capturing some events (using Jquery.Event) inside an iframe, in order to feed an array. Basically I am capturing events like:

```
var events=[]
$('#ifrm').contents().on('change click focus keypress select submit', function(evt){ 
  events.push($.Event(evt))
})
```

Now, I am trying to trigger (replay) all events in event array like:

```
$.each(events, function(i,evt){
   $('#ifrm').contents().trigger(evt)
})
```

Is it supposed to work or I am missing something?

Comment: You're triggering the events on a completely different element that they were originally fired on. What exactly are you trying to achieve as this is a rather odd way of doing things

Comment: I am just recording events from iframe to reproduce it later. Why different element? Element is an iframe (#ifrm), as stated on my question.

Comment: The elements bubble up the DOM from the element they were fired. You then re-fire those elements on every single element in the DOM as you use `contents().trigger()`

Comment: Thanks. Probably I have to select each target (originalEvent.target).

Answer (score 0):

You have an error.. you forgot an s.

```
events.push($.Event(evt))
```

Also, see [this link for more  help.](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: also on `$.each(events...`

Comment: ^ Yes, I missed that one.

Comment: It was just a typo to transcript here. I will  edit my question.

Comment: @charlietfl may I know why?